# Derivative as an onto linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $D$ be the differentiation operator, $I = [0,1]$ and $C_{b}^{1}(I)$ be the space of functions $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ and $Df$ are continuous and bounded, with the norm $\|f\|_{C^{1}} = \|f\|_{\infty} + \|Df\|_{\infty}$. Likewise $C_{b}^{0}(I)$ is the set of bounded continuous functions with the norm $\|f\|_{C^{0}} = \|f\|_{\infty}$.

If I understand correctly, $D$ as a linear map from $C_{b}^{1}(I) \to C_{b}^{0}(I)$ is continuous and onto; for instance we have a preimage of any $g \in C_{b}^{0}(I)$ in the function $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g(y)dy$ in $C_{b}^{1}(I)$.

I want to loosen the restriction that the functions are defined on a closed interval. For example  we will run into problems if we consider $D$ as an operator from $C_{b}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ to $C_{b}^{0}(\mathbb{R})$, since, although $D$ is still continuous, even a constant function like $g(x) = 5$ will not have preimage.

Is it possible to keep the onto property by considering some intermediate/other spaces, for example by restricting $C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$ by adding an integrability condition? Any references would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you replace $C_b^1(I)$ by the space of absolutely continuous functions on $I$ and $C_b^0(I)$ by $L^1(I)$, then Lebesgue's fundamental theorem of Calculus gives you surjectivity.

Comment: You can extend to bounded functions f with continuous derivative and bounded support, that is, when f=0 except on a bounded set or reals.